# sysV init.d: what does the priority really mean?

Tags: linux, init, rc, sysv

The docs for `chkconfig` are a bit loose on what the priority number actually means, and the docs for `init` don't even mention priority on my machine.

Say you have the following:

```
/etc/rc.d/rc3.d/S01foo
/etc/rc.d/rc3.d/S02bar
```

Which one is run first?  The one with the higher priority (bar)?  Or is the priority number more of a start-order number, so the lower numbers are started before the higher numbers?

What if it was `K01foo` and `K02bar`. Which one would be stopped first?  Greater priority one, or is it more of a "stop-order"?

Answer (score 2):

After some experimentation I was able to figure it out.
It's more of an 'order from least to greatest' process.
In other words, the lower the priority number, the sooner the job will stop/start.

`S01foo` will start before `S02bar`, and `K01foo` will stop before `K02bar`.

Hopefully this saves someone 15 minutes.